# android I set fontface such as songti.ttc，but my textview setting is gravity=“center” ,as result ,it does not work on android 5.0 lollipop

Tags: android, textview

android I set fontface such as songti.ttc，but my textview setting is gravity=“center” ,as result ,it does not work on Android 5.0 lollipop,how can I fix it?

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/special_layer_list_back"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
```

Comment: can you attach your UI? how does it look?

Comment: can you show us result and what is problem(Issue)